# Я создал бота вк на питоне, как оптимизировать код?

Tags: python

Как оптимизировать этот код? Мне нужно сделать так чтобы некоторые условные операторы if проверялись только после условного оператора if перед ним. Например: Когда пишешь "Привет", появляется как бы меню в котором написаны команды "1","2",
но если взять другую команду из другого блока например "1.1" то она тоже будет работать. Как сделать так чтобы этого не было? Никак не получается.

```html
import vk_api
import time
import random
from params import vsesth,mon,diap
token = "Ваш токен группы"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk._auth_token()

while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
            body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
            if body.lower() == "привет" or body.lower() == "начало" or body.lower() == "начать":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет!\n________________________________\n"
                                                     "Вот мои команды:\nНапиши число чтобы выбрать\n________________________________\n"
                                                     "1 - Рандомный стих \n"
                                                     "2 - Игры\n"
                                                     "3 - Ещё не придумал\n"
                                                     "________________________________\nСвязь - https://vk.com/alex3301"
                           ,"random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": random.choice(vsesth), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "2":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Напиши число чтобы выбрать\n_______________________________\n"
                                                     "1.1 - Орел & Решка\n2.1 - Рандомное число\n3.1 - Скоро\n"
                                                     " ___________________\nНапиши\"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                            ,"random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1.1":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Напиши число чтобы выбрать\n_______________________________\n"
                                                     "1.3 - Орел или Решка рандомно\n2.3 - Выбрать сторону\n3.3 - Скоро\n"
                                                     " ___________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                            ,"random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1.3":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Тебе выпало: " + random.choice(mon) +
                                          "\n _____________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                             ,"random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "2.3":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Выбери сторну:\n ________________\n1.4 - Орёл\n 2.4 - Решка"
                                                     " \n ________________ \nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                              ,"random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1.4":
                if random.choice(mon) == "Орёл": vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ты выйграл!"
                                                     "\n ________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                              ,"random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                else: vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ты проиграл!"
                                                     "\n ________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                              ,"random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "2.4":
                if random.choice(mon) == "Решка":
                    vk.method("messages.send",
                              {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ты выйграл!"
                                                         "\n ________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                                  , "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                else:
                    vk.method("messages.send",
                              {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ты проиграл!"
                                                         "\n ________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                                  , "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})

            elif body.lower() == "2.1":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Выбери диапазон - напиши число\n___________________________________\n"
                                             "1.2 - От 1 до 10\n"
                                             "1.3 - От 1 до 20\n"           
                                             "1.4 - От 1 до 30\n"           
                                             "1.5 - От 1 до 50\n"          
                                             "1.6 - От 1 до 100\n"         
                                          "_____________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                             , "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1.2":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Тебе выпало: " + random.choice(diap[0]) +
                                                     "\n _____________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                             , "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1.3":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Тебе выпало: " + random.choice(diap[1]) +
                                                     "\n _____________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                            , "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1.4":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Тебе выпало: " + random.choice(diap[2]) +
                                                     "\n _____________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                            , "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1.5":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Тебе выпало: " + random.choice(diap[3]) +
                                                     "\n _____________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                            , "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "1.6":
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Тебе выпало: " + random.choice(diap[4]) +
                                                     "\n _____________________\nНапиши \"начало\" чтобы вернутся назад"
                            , "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})


            else:
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Не понял тебя!\n___________________\n"
                                                     "Вот мои команды:\nНапиши число чтобы выбрать\n_______________________________\n"
                                                     "1 - Рандомный стих \n"
                                                     "2 - Игры\n"
                                                     "3 - Ещё не придумал"
                           ,"random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Идентифицировать пользователя, хранить его историю команд в базе, написать конечный автомат возможных переходов, profit?

Comment: А не проще ли использовать клавиатуру? [Поподробнее](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_3)